# Use a switch statement to branch based upon a selection of Boolean values : Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, random, boolean, switch-statement

I have this method:

```
-(void) setRandomConnectionForFloorTile:(Tile *)ft andConnectionTile:(Tile *)ct
{
    BOOL ftLeftConnection = [ft leftConnection];
    BOOL ftTopConnection = [ft topConnection];
    BOOL ftRightConnection = [ft rightConnection];
    BOOL ftBottomConnection = [ft bottomConnection];

    switch (arc4random() %4 + 1)
    {
        case 1:
            if ([_toBuild returnTileOfType:@"FloorTile" atPosition:CGPointMake([ft screenPosition].x - [[ft sprite] size].width, [ft screenPosition].y)])
            {
                [self setRandomConnectionForFloorTile:ft andConnectionTile:ct];
            }
            else
            {
                [ct setScreenPosition:CGPointMake([ft screenPosition].x - [[ft sprite] size].width, [ft screenPosition].y)];
                [[_toBuild tiles] addObject:ct];
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if ([_toBuild returnTileOfType:@"FloorTile" atPosition:CGPointMake([ft screenPosition].x, [ft screenPosition].y + [[ft sprite] size].height)])
            {
                [self setRandomConnectionForFloorTile:ft andConnectionTile:ct];
            }
            else
            {
                [ct setScreenPosition:CGPointMake([ft screenPosition].x, [ft screenPosition].y + [[ft sprite] size].height)];
                [[_toBuild tiles] addObject:ct];
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            if ([_toBuild returnTileOfType:@"FloorTile" atPosition:CGPointMake([ft screenPosition].x + [[ft sprite] size].width, [ft screenPosition].y)])
            {
                [self setRandomConnectionForFloorTile:ft andConnectionTile:ct];
            }
            else
            {
                [ct setScreenPosition:CGPointMake([ft screenPosition].x + [[ft sprite] size].width, [ft screenPosition].y)];
                [[_toBuild tiles] addObject:ct];
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            if ([_toBuild returnTileOfType:@"FloorTile" atPosition:CGPointMake([ft screenPosition].x, [ft screenPosition].y - [[ft sprite] size].height)])
            {
                [self setRandomConnectionForFloorTile:ft andConnectionTile:ct];
            }
            else
            {
                [ct setScreenPosition:CGPointMake([ft screenPosition].x, [ft screenPosition].y - [[ft sprite] size].height)];
                [[_toBuild tiles] addObject:ct];
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the problem that this code produces is unnecessary repetition and demand of system resource.

Basically, I have my four Boolean values declared at the beginning, which dictate which side a tile may be connected on. So, when, say ftLeftConnection is false, and only false, it may have a tile placed immediately to it's left.

I want to create a switch statement (or some other form of method), which will enable me to only execute random cases for only those Boolean values that are false. It doesn't make sense to try to connect a Tile to another Tile's immediate right if I have the information that tells me that there is already a Tile there.

Reuben

Comment: You can use array and save only true boolean into it. And then instead of "arc4random() %4 + 1" use "arc4random()%array.Count + 1" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum {
    Left = 0,
    Up,
    Right,
    Down
};

int valid_directions[] = {0,0,0,0};
int num_valid_directions = 0;
BOOL established_directions[] = {ftLeftConnection, ftTopConnection, ftRightConnection, ftBottomConnection};
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
    if( !established_directions[i] ){
        valid_directions[num_valid_directions++] = i;
    }
}

int chosen_direction = valid_directions[arc4random_uniform(num_valid_directions)];

switch( chosen_direction ){
    case Left:
        // etc.
```

This assumes that there's at least one possible direction.